# What is the pathway to Lie Groups theory

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups

I only have an undergraduate level math but am quite fascinated with how lie groups are applied in elementary particle physics.  Any advice on how I can learn lie groups theory (with an application to physics in mind)?  What pre-requsite do I need, and how much group theory I need to master before I can start lie groups, and how much lie group theory do I need to understand elementary particle theory?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194419/whats-a-good-place-to-learn-lie-groups, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461029/getting-started-with-lie-groups, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634437/lie-groups-pre-requisites-and-reference.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice!